# Bootstrap5 collapsible navbar not working in mobile view

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, angular11

I am working with Bootstrap 5 Navigation bar's collapse button functionality in Angular 11. It works fine in desktop site but not in mobile view. One reason I am thinking is that I don't have popper.js installed in the app. Do I need popper.js with Bootstrap5(angular.json file given below)?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A third link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        ]
```

[image]

Comment: Popper is included in the Bootstrap bundle file. As you can see by the demo above, your markup is fine. Console errors? It seems from the screenshot that CSS isn't loading either.